# Can not prevent input field get focus in Android

Tags: javascript

Here are many items:

[Figure 1](http://d.pr/i/cNQF)

When click one of them will expand and the inner input field dispaly.
The question is in mobile device the inner input box will get focus when touch the item but not just expand it:

[Figure 2](http://d.pr/i/cWzw)

The html is like:

`<div>
  <h2>Write</h2>
  <p><input type="text" value="Content"></p>
</div>`

In iOS device prevent this action by listening the touchend event of item and prevent the default action by 'evt.preventDefault()'.But in android device(test in 2.2.1) it not works.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default action on `touchstart` as well.

Comment: can not scroll the page if prevent default action when touch start.

Comment: @differui You can prevent it only on the input. You would not be able to scroll if you start scrolling from the input though.